# Rails Postgres Error GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In SQLite (development) I don't have any errors, but in production with Postgres I get the following error. I don't really understand the error.

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  column "commits.updated_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...mmits"."user_id" = 1 GROUP BY mission_id ORDER BY updated_at...
                                                             ^
: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, mission_id AS mission_id FROM "commits"  WHERE "commits"."user_id" = 1 GROUP BY mission_id ORDER BY updated_at DESC
```

My controller method:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @commits = @user.commits.order("updated_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(25)
    @missions_commits = @commits.group("mission_id").count.length
  end
```

**UPDATE:**

So i digged further into this PostgreSQL specific annoyance and I am surprised that this exception is not mentioned in the Ruby on Rails Guide.

I am using `psql (PostgreSQL) 9.1.11`

So from what I understand, I need to specify which column that should be used whenever you use the `GROUP_BY` clause. I thought using `SELECT` would help, which can be annoying if you need to `SELECT` a lot of columns.

[Interesting discussion here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/1515)

Anyways, when I look at the error, everytime the cursor is pointed to `updated_at`. In the SQL query, rails will always `ORDER BY updated_at`. So I have tried this horrible query:

```
@commits.group("mission_id, date(updated_at)")
        .select("date(updated_at), count(mission_id)")
        .having("count(mission_id) > 0")
        .order("count(mission_id)").length
```

which gives me the following SQL

```
SELECT  date(updated_at), count(mission_id) 
FROM "commits"  
WHERE "commits"."user_id" = 1 
GROUP BY mission_id, date(updated_at) 
HAVING count(mission_id) > 0 
ORDER BY updated_at DESC, count(mission_id) 
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

the error is the same.

**Note** that no matter what it will ORDER BY updated_at, even if I wanted to order by something else.

Also I don't want to group the records by updated_at just by mission_id.

This PostgreSQL error is just misleading and has little explanation to solving it. I have tried many formulas from the stackoverflow sidebar, nothing works and always the same error.

UPDATE 2:
So I got it to work, but it needs to group the `updated_at` because of the automatic `ORDER BY updated_at`. How do I count only by `mission_id`?

```
@missions_commits = @commits.group("mission_id, updated_at").count("mission_id").size
```

Comment: does it helps to write `count('mission_id')`. otherwise make two statements. the error message is quite clear?

Comment: The error message is not clear to me. Also I believe I was using rails convention. So I am a bit suprised with this error. I didn't write a custom SQL. I will try out the count(mission_id). Also why would it work in sqlite and not postgres???

Comment: (1) SQLite and MySQL have a rather fast'n'loose interpretation of SQL, PostgreSQL prefers not to second guess you. (2) If you're deploying on PostgreSQL, develop on PostgreSQL. No ORM will protect you from databases differences, database portability is a myth unless you do it yourself. (3) Have you looked at any of the **Related** questions in the sidebar? This is a very common error.

Comment: postgresql is more strict with sql standards. therefor the group by and the order by are related to each other.

Comment: the error comes from the method `.order('updated_at DESC')`. This is a rails method, why would it create a problem with Postgres? I am not trying to change Rails, just figuring out how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guest you want to show general number of distinct Missions related with Commits, anyway it won't be number on page.

Try this:

```
@commits = @user.commits.order("updated_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(25)
@missions_commits = @user.commits.distinct.count(:mission_id)
```

However if you want to get the number of distinct Missions on page I suppose it should be:

```
@missions_commits = @commits.collect(&:mission_id).uniq.count
```

**Update**

In Rails 3, `distinct` did not exist, but pure SQL counting should be used this way:

```
@missions_commits = @user.commits.count(:mission_id, distinct: true)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the issue is not from the `@mission_commits` but from `@commits`.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, so why `mission_id` is used in query? Paging query should have `LIMIT`. Could you check again?

Comment: Normally (in my development test, which is sqlite) `@missions_commits = 3`. When I tried `@user.commits.distinct.count(:mission_id) = 0`. When I tried `@commits.collect(&:mission_id).uniq = 2` and in the console I get `undefined method `collect' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: So I ended up giving up with the .group function that just doesn't work the way I want it. So i followed your clue with `distinct`. I tried your function but it didn't work, so here is how I wrote mine: `@missions_commits = @user.commits.select("DISTINCT mission_id").size`

Comment: Thanks for points. I've investigated why `distinct` didn't work for you and I updated the answer. Using SQL count is usually faster because result is always one row. Also add an index on [:user_id, :mission_id] and this will be light fast. In your present query lets have an user who commited to 200 missions then the result will be 200 rows array just to count its size - not very scalable.

Answer (score 1):

See the docs for PostgreSQL GROUP BY here:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY

Basically, unlike Sqlite (and MySQL) postgres requires that any columns selected or ordered on must appear in an aggregate function or the group by clause.

If you think it through, you'll see that this actually makes sense.  Sqlite/MySQL cheat under the hood and silently drop those fields (not sure that's technically what happens).

Or thinking about it another way if you are grouping by a field, what's the point of ordering it?  How would that even make sense unless you also had an aggregate function on the ordered field?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I just don't see how i can fix the error with Rails.